# How to re-write this URL in PHP using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am working on one website.

On this website, porfile URL currently is like this:

http://eprofile.co/eprofile.php?user=degroundshaker

I want to rewrite this URL as:

http://eprofile.co/degroundshaker

This, is addon domain so its files are under a folder called "eprofile.co" in my cPanel and there is one .htaccess file.

So, i need solution and please let me know what rule i need to add and what should be the complete format in .htaccess

I m newbie in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /eprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Shall i write only these two lines in .htaccess??
Currently my .htaccess is blank

Comment: Well, I got following error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@eprofile.myblogis.in and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /eprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Then you need to change all of your profile links from looking like this:

```
http://eprofile.co/eprofile.php?user=degroundshaker
```

to looking like this:

```
http://eprofile.co/degroundshaker
```

---

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/eprofile.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /eprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much...

it worked fine in my server online..

But im also working on it at localhost

So, in my localhost, path is something like 

cv/

Under root folder "www", there is another folder called "cv", So im opening site at my localhost with this URL
http://localhost/cv

Now i want to write for its .htaccess file as well. I copy pasted same code there, but got 500 error



Please help me in it as well. WOuld be really great of you :)

Comment: Hey, your this piece of code worked fine

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /eprofile.php?user=$1 [L]


but, in my localhost, it giving 404 error - Not Found

The requested URL /eprofile.php was not found on this server.

What should i do?

Comment: @degroundshaker You don't have `eprofile.php` on your local server?

Comment: Yes, i have that under CV folder :O

Comment: hey, got it.. I jus removed "/" before eprofile.php in .htaccess and it worked like charm :))

Tx man.. you vanished all ma tension .. ;) cheers